# Is a certain square root of $-1$ an element of $\Omega_{4l}^+(q)$?

Tags: finite-groups, classical-groups

Let $F$ be a finite field of order a power $p^r$ of some odd prime $p$ for some positive integer $r$, and $c$ a the generator of $F^{\times}$ , is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & A_{2l\times 2l}\\
B_{2l\times 2l} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
an element of $\Omega_{4l}^+(q)$ for $l\geq 2$, where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, as it is a square element in ${\rm O}_{4l}(q)$ and so its spinor norm is $+1$, and hence it is belongs to $\Omega_{4l}(q)$.